# Why is the didSelectItemAtIndexPath not getting called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UILabel in collection view cell and when I select it I want the background of the label to change color, but nothing happens when I click a cell? Why is that and how do I fix it? nothing is getting printed in the console.

```
class newview: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("called")
    var cell: customcell = timecollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! customcell

    cell.clabel.tag = indexPath.item
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "choose:")
    cell.clabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    cell.clabel.userInteractionEnabled = true

    cell.clabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.clabel.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.clabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor

     }

func choose(gest: UITapGestureRecognizer){
     let label: UILabel = gest.view as! UILabel
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
     }  
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: Have you implemented `UICollectionViewDelegate` and set the delegate on the collectionView?

Comment: Yes I have done that.

Comment: That's all ? Where are you setting it? BTW you should name your class starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: In the storyboard I am setting it. The collection view is populated, so the delegate is set.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Delete delegate in storyboard and try to reconnect delegate method

Comment: I did that, but I get the same result. I have a feeling the uilabel being on top of the cell is causing a problem.

Comment: @stackerleet you don't need to set the delegate to populate your collection view. You only need to set the data source

Comment: @stackerleet again can you post a screen shot so I can check if you correctly set your view controller as the delegate ?

Comment: check that the collectionview is placed on top of scrollview or not!

Comment: Yeah I'd put a breakpoint within the method to better confirm if it's getting called. Also I'd use the view debugger to see if your collection view is beneath any other views. Also make sure user interaction is enabled. Additionally, make sure you let the delegate method autocomplete: if even one character is off it won't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are tapping on label to change the color of label. `didSelectitemAtIndexpath` will not called if you tap the label. For that you need to add UITapGestureRecognizer to your label.

In your cellForRow try setting `label.tag = indexPath.row` and then add `tapGesture` to the label. And in the target of it change the color of label. And don't forget to set `userInteractionEnable = true` as `label` property.

**EDIT**

```
 @IBAction func btnTapped(gest: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Called")
      let label:UILabel = (gest.view as! UILabel) // Type cast it with the class for which you have added gesture
      label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
  }
```

Comment: I updated my code with your advice but how do I access the labels background etc in the gesture function?

Comment: When I click the cell I, the console does not print called

Comment: You need to add tapgesture in cellForRow, not in didselect

Comment: Is it possible to only on item to be selected? Like if the user tries to select more than one label only the latest one they choose will be highlighted.

Comment: Yes its possible..for that u need to store indexpath of selected item, then check if saved indexpath == currentIndexpath, then change bacground color of lable, otherwise change background color of other label.

Comment: So create a global variable equal to an int and inside the gesture function set the tag equal to the global variable and in the cellForItemAtIndexPath check if it is equal to the current indexPath?

Comment: I am confused on what to do in the cellForItemAtIndexPath function after I have the global variable equal to the selected label.tag